# How to "Destructure" a dict to create a new one?

Tags: python

Finally getting around to learning python...

I have a dict with many keys. I want to create a new one with an added key. This is how I'd do it in JavaScript, "destructuring" `obj1` to create `obj2` with a new `c` key:

```js
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 }
const obj2 = { ...obj1, c: 3 }

// or
someFunction({
    ...obj1,
    c: 3
})
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this in python? Or is it simply:

```py
>>> obj1={ "a": 1, "b": 2 }
>>> obj2 = obj1.copy()
>>> obj2['c'] = 3
```

Which I find horribly ugly, because now I need a variable, I can't construct the dict inline as a `def` parameter, like i did in the `someFunction` call in JavaScript.

(Also easy in Perl:

```perl
my %obj1 = ( a: 1, b: 2 );
someFunction( { %obj1, c: 3 } );
```

)

Comment: In JavaScript, this is an example of spread, not destructuring, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary unpacking [in dict literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) ([PEP 448](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/), implemented in Python 3.5):

```py
obj2 = {**obj1, "c": 3}
```

Comment: Instead of unpacking, consider dict union (`obj1 | {'c': 3}` in 3.9+) instead for readability and (probably - not sure) performance.

Comment: @STerliakov: Unless the union is with a preexisting dict, I don’t consider that more readable, and I definitely don’t expect it to perform better.

Comment: From a quick `timeit` test, seems both are equivalent in terms of performance for tiny dictionaries. However, `merge` looks much cleaner to me (cf. `super().get_context_data(**kwargs) | {'foo': 'bar}` vs `{**super().get_context_data(), 'foo': 'bar'}` - the former looks better to me, esp. considering line breaks with longer additions)